# Is this validation almost correct? 

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I have a form that students are using to rank 6 classes from 1 to 6.  If they select Math as "1" (the hardest), then I don't want them to be able to select another subject as the hardest. The form will obviously give them the option to select "1" for each subject,  but I want to use validations to protect against submission of a form that doesn't follow instructions

This is a snippet from the form

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label(:math, "Mathp") %>
    <%= f.select:math, 1..6 %> </br>
    </div>

<div class="field">
    <%= f.label(:french, "French") %>
    <%= f.select:french, 1..6 %> </br>
    </div>
```

I was going to use a validation method like this, but I don't think the logic of it works (i.e. it doesn't guard against every possible situation) and it's probably shitty (non-functional) code too, because i'm just learning how to code (actually I've been failing at it for quite a while now). Can you suggest improvements?

```
validates :rank_favorites 


...

def rank_favorites

unless :math != :french && :french != :history && :history != :spanish && :spanish != :art && :art != :physed return false

end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `rank_favorites` is, sadly, way off but ignorance can be fixed through learning. You're just comparing a bunch of symbols and that doesn't do anything useful (at least not as far as you're concerned), you're validator reduces to this:

```
unless false && false && false && false && false return false
```

which is equivalent to:

```
unless false return false
```

You probably want to use [`validate :rank_favorites`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods) (not `validates`) and your validator would [add error messages](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#errors-base) instead of simply return a boolean:

```
validate :rank_favorites

#...

def rank_favorites
  ranks = [math, french, history, spanish, art, physed]
  if(ranks.include?(nil))
    errors[:base] << 'Rank all of them you lazy person!'
  elsif(ranks.uniq.length != ranks.length)
    errors[:base] << 'You fail at ranking, no duplicates allowed.'
  end
end
```

The [`Array#uniq`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-uniq) method will produce a copy of your array with the duplicates removed, if the lengths don't match then something was removed and you had duplicate entries.

You might want to spend some time reading the validations guide:

> [Active Record Validations and Callbacks](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html)

Comment: Thanks, I did read the validations guide, but I don't really learn unless I try to write them (crappy as they are) and then get someone to help me fix them. learn by doing for me.

Comment: This could be tightened up slightly as I suggested in my answer to ensure that the ranked numbers are actually between 1 and 6 and not just any 6 unique numbers. You shouldnt rely on your form select box to limit the values submitted. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: @Aditya: And if you wanted to do that then `ranks.sort != (1 .. ranks.length).to_a` would probably be the best option unless you wanted separate error messages for each condition (missing ranks, duplicates, out of bounds, ...).

Comment: @mu is too short, yes it absolutely be a better idea.

Answer (score 1):

You could always do something like this:

```
validate do
  unless [math, french, history, spanish, art, physed].uniq.length == 6
    errors.add(:base, :doh_theyre_not_unique_error)
  end
end
```

This really feels like it could use some JS form love though.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I'm going to look at JS validations later (for learning experience). However, can you please expalin :base and :doh_theyre_not_unique_error -- is that latter an error message? Where can I add the error message?

Comment: @macek Of course, what I meant was that he should use both.  Server validation as the safety net, but JS in the form to improve the UI (not to validate).  E.g. a script that keeps you from selecting the same number twice, or a jquery-ui style sortable list.

Comment: @michael `:doh_theyre_not_unique_error` is an example of a key used for `i18n` translation.  I was joking a bit with the name.  In reality it might be `:duplicate_score` or something, which would correspond to a key in your translations file that held the message, e.g. "No duplicate ranks allowed".  Read more [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html).

Answer (score 1):

so what you really want to do is ensure no subject gets the same ranking :)

```
:math != :french # => true ALWAYS because they internalized constant strings which are obviously different
```

If you did..

```
self.math != self.french # => this is comparing variables now. much better. BUT Still wrong in terms of the logic you want
```

How about

```
if [self.math,self.french,self.history,self.spanish,self.art,self.physed].uniq.sort != [1,2,3,4,5,6])
  errors.add(:base,"Repeated rankings")
end
```

Comment: ..and you can safely remove the "self." noise. Ruby will automatically resolve them to be methods that rails would provide based on your columns.

Comment: thanks a lot. can you explain :base? is that something you arbitrarily named?

Comment: @michael one can add errors to the base model or a particular field. To add errors to the model and no field in particular, we use :base. If we needed to add the error to a specific column, we would use that field name. BTW field = attribute = dbcolumnname.